# UIImage isKindOfClass issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, uiimage

This is my code in my application,

```
    [imageview setAlpha:1.0f];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[pages objectAtIndex:swipeCount]]]];
    [imageview setFrame:CGRectMake(-300, 0, 1368, 1000)];
```

Edit:

```
      pages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"page1",@"page2",@"page3",@"page4",@"page5",@"page6",@"page7b",@"page8",@"page9",@"page10a",@"page11",@"page12",@"page13b",@"page14",@"page15",@"page16a",@"page17",@"page18",@"page19",@"page20",@"page21",@"page22",@"page23",@"page24",@"page25", nil];
      imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
```

its working properly,  problems except when the app enters background and comes back to foreground shows the following error,

```
  *** -[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e8b10
```

What wrong with the code?
Please help me out

Comment: are you using ARC? How are you initiating your UIImageView and your Pages Array.

Comment: @kushyar yes..Am using ARC

Comment: great, can you edit your post so we can see how you are initiating 'pages' array and your UIImageView?

Comment: @kushyar question updated

Comment: what about swipeCount? how is that being initiated and retrieved

Comment: @kushyar swipecount is int

Comment: Please alloc a property to your UIImage and synthesize it , your UIImage object is not getting memory

Comment: @IronManGill i did again it shows the same error

Comment: @kushyar any posiibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to allocate memory to your `UIImage`. What is basically happening is that your image is being temporarily stored in the memory and deallocated upon closing the app so iOS could allocate that memory to more immediate needs. You can fix that as below. I'm also gonna allocate a string since `stringWithFormat` returns an `autorelease` `String`.

```
NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat::@"%@.png",[pages objectAtIndex:swipeCount]];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:myImage];
[imageview setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using properties. Make array,imageView as a property and then use 
`self.pages` and `self.imageView`

see this good article on properties

[Objective-c properties](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial)